# What is the fastest/safest method to iterate over a HashSet?

Tags: c#, performance, iteration, hashset

I'm still quite new to C#, but noticed the advantages through forum postings of using a `HashSet` instead of a `List` in specific cases.

My current case isn't that I'm storing a tremendous amount of data in a single `List` exectly, but rather than I'm having to check for members of it often.

The catch is that I do indeed need to iterate over it as well, but the order they are stored or retrieved doesn't actually matter.

I've read that for each loops are actually slower than for next, so how else could I go about this in the fastest method possible?

The number of `.Contains()` checks I'm doing is definitely hurting my performance with lists, so at least comparing to the performance of a `HashSet` would be handy.

Edit: I'm currently using lists, iterating through them in numerous locations, and different code is being executed in each location. Most often, the current lists contain point coordinates that I then use to refer to a 2 dimensional array for that I then do some operation or another based on the criteria of the list.

If there's not a direct answer to my question, that's fine, but I assumed there might be other methods of iterating over a `HashSet` than just `foreach` cycle. I'm currently in the dark as to what other methods there might even be, what advantages they provide, etc. Assuming there are other methods, I also made the assumption that there would be a typical preferred method of choice that is only ignored when it doesn't suite the needs (my needs are pretty basic).

As far as prematurely optimizing, I already know using the lists as I am is a bottleneck. How to go about helping this issue is where I'm getting stuck. Not even stuck exactly, but I didn't want to re-invent the wheel by testing repeatedly only to find out I'm already doing it the best way I could (this is a large project with over 3 months invested, lists are everywhere, but there are definitely ones that I do not want duplicates, have a lot of data, need not be stored in any specific order, etc).

Comment: What are you planning to do in the iteration? Execute code? Count something?

Comment: You are prematurely optimizing.  Now that doesn't mean you should ignore the performance implications of your data structures and code entirely, but if you need the semantics of a HashSet then your next step is to profile the iteration in the context of your program and how it will typically be run.  If the iteration is not a performance bottleneck then move on, it isn't worth your time.  Don't just assume that it will be, test.

Comment: I do not know anything about the answer, but my convention says that the fastest method wont be the safest and the safest wont be the fastest. I believe if one method is both fastest and safest, then there need be no other methods. I may be wrong.

Comment: What are your performance requirements? Have you measured the performance. You should go for the most readable code and optimize only if you pinpointed that peace of code to be a performance bottleneck in the system.

Comment: Just try it, you'll get a better (ie taking all context into account) result and faster than asking here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A foreach loop has a small amount of addition overhead on an indexed collections (like an array).
This is mostly because the foreach does a little more bounds checking than a for loop.

HashSet does not have an indexer so you have to use the enumerator.

In this case foreach is efficient as it only calls MoveNext() as it moves through the collection.

Also Parallel.ForEach can dramatically improve your performance, depending on the work you are doing in the loop and the size of your HashSet.

As mentioned before profiling is your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be iterating over a hashset in the first place to determine if an item is in it.  You should use the HashSet (not the LINQ) contains method.  The HashSet is designed such that it won't need to look through every item to see if any given value is inside of the set.  That is what makes it so powerful for searching over a List.

Comment: He says in his question that he needs to be able both search and iterate, not iterate to search.

Comment: I don't understand why this is upvoted. Question is not about searching, it's about iterating.

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly answering the question in the header, but more concerning your specific problem:

I would make your own `Collection` object that uses both a `HashSet` and a `List` internally. Iterating is fast as you can use the List, checking for `Contains` is fast as you can use the HashSet. Just make it an `IEnumerable` and you can use this Collection in `foreach` as well.

The downside is more memory, but there are only twice as many references to object, not twice as many objects. Worst case scenario it's only twice as much memory, but you seem much more concerned with performance.

Adding, checking, and iterating are fast this way, only removal is still O(N) because of the `List`.

EDIT: If removal needs to be O(1) as well, use a [doubly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) instead of a regular list, and make the hashSet a `Dictionary<KeyType, Cell>` instead. You can check the dictionary for Contains, but also to find the cell with the data in it fast, so removal from the data structure is fast.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue, where the HashSet suits very well the addition of unique elements, but is very slow when getting elements in a for loop. I solved it by converting the HashSet to array and then running the for over it.