# .NET - what is a "double pointer list"?

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38612092/8781415) post from a few years back that mentions a "double pointer list". Apparently it is a version of `List<T>` with O(1) removal. How do I make one, and how do I use it?

(Sorry, I'd make this a comment to the linked post, but I lack the reputation to make comments)

Comment: Do you mean a linked list (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx) which has both O(1) insertion and removal?

Comment: The more common name is **doubly linked list**...I think. The reason it is called double (pointer or link) is because it has a reference to the previous link and a 2nd reference to the next link.

Comment: O(1) strictly refers to the removal itself, though, right? Finding the node to remove is not O(1) unless you manage searching in a different way, correct?

Comment: That is simply a poor choice of words by the author of the answer that you cited. They are referring to creating your own derived class which uses both a List<T> and a HashSet<T> internally to provide different ways to access the items in the collection. "Double pointer" in this case is more accurately termed "double reference".

Comment: Thank you Mr Benningfield, that clears things up. That was my plan if double pointer lists turned out to not be what I was looking for.

Comment: @KennethK.: The post cited suggests creating a doubly linked list for fast insertion and removal, and a hash set for quickly looking up the item's location in the linked list based on... what?  Surely not the index, because then there are still O(n) updates that need to be made in the hash set on removal. Without more information about what the writer of that post had in mind it is hard to say what data structure they are actually talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out they don't exist, the author of that post chose their words poorly. Mark Benningfield answered in the comments of this post.

Comment: I never said it was a "version of List<T>" though, but I did have a poor choice of words using "double pointer" instead of "doubly linked". Awell. On the plus side Eric talked about me.

My answer was also "Not strictly answering the question in the header, but more concerning your specific problem", by "make your own Collection object that uses both a HashSet and a List internally". I was not intending my answer to be fully compatible with any reader's wishes.

Comment: As for the data structure I had in mind, the original question already talked about using a HashSet, so there is some way to derive a hash key from an object fast. A linked list would be a bunch of Cell objects with three members, a Cell previous, a Cell next, and a Data data. A HashSet could just as well be of generic type <KeyType,Cell>, so that you would have the exact Cell(or minimal iteration, HashSets eh) holding the Data, and can thus remove it quickly, without iterating the doubly linked list.